# How to check access based on both userId and dataId using the Google Healthcare Consent API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-healthcare-api

Users can add other users to their careteam and assign a role to each member of their careteam.
When accessing the profile of another user, the system should check if the user gave consent to do this.

Question 1: How to check if user X gave consent to view the profile of user Y?

Question 2: Can Google Healthcare Consent API handle this?

Question 3: Does it make sense to use Google Healthcare Consent API for this?

#### Current concept

Example use case: Grandma is the patient and Alice is taking care of her in a "doctor" context.

In the current setup, there is a dataMapping for each careteam member:

```
{
  userId: 'id_of_alice',
  dataId: 'users/id_of_grandma/profile',
  resourceAttributes: [
    {
      attributeDefinitionId: 'careteam',
      values: ['doctor']
    }
  ]
}
```

I used two methods to check if Alice has access to Grandma's profile:

#### [checkDataAccess](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/how-tos/consent-access-determination#making_consent_access_determinations_for_specific_data_elements)

This method takes a `dataId` as input and returns true if consent was given to ANY user.
That's not very useful... Should I lookup the userId on my side and pass the role in  `requestAttributes`? (What does the Consent API offer then?)

#### [evaluateUserConsents](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/how-tos/consent-access-determination#making_an_access_determination_for_all_consents_for_a_user)

This method takes a `userId` as input and returns all consented dataIds. This does not seem scalable. A doctor may have access to thousands of patients.

Answer (score 0):

According to the current documentation [1] it is not possible to check access based on both UserId and DataId. It is documented that each has its own process [2][3].

For your question #1 You would need to implement some sort of filtering in your application to be able to have what you are looking for.

For question #2 it seems that the Consent management API currently does not offer that functionality.

For your question #3, the consent management API can help you to manage the access of the users by applying policies [4].

It is important to mention that the Consent Management API is still in beta [5] and new features could be included in the future.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/how-tos/consent-access-determination
[2]https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/how-tos/consent-access-determination#making_consent_access_determinations_for_specific_data_elements
[3]https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/how-tos/consent-access-determination#making_an_access_determination_for_all_consents_for_a_user
[4]https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/how-tos/consent-policies
[5]https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/release-notes#October_08_2020